# How to add scroll bar to views titles

Tags: views

I created a views block to display the titles of nodes. I placed the block in the left side region. In order to see all the titles, I need to scroll down the page. Instead, I would like to add scroll bar to the views titles so I can simply scroll the bar to see the titles. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need some css to do this task. Pick a class from view content html and fix its height and set overflow-y property to scroll. Example snippet below -

```
.view-content{
    height: 50px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: overflow-y: auto; is nicer imo because the scroll disappears if the content isn't 50px high.